# How can i find an array of objects out of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have an array

```
let data = [
    {
        A_ID: 'ABC',
        C_Array: ["123","456","789"]
    },

    {
        A_ID: 'DEF',
        C_Array: ["444","555","666"]
    }
]
```

and i want to create a new array like so that for each C_Array i get its coresponding A_ID,

like

```
let newData = [
    {
        A_ID: 'ABC',
        C_ArrayValue: "123"
    },
    {
        A_ID: 'ABC',
        C_ArrayValue: "456"
    },

]
```

How can i do that in JS

Comment: What have you tried? This should be pretty doable using either `Array.prototype.reduce` or a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  {
    A_ID: 'ABC',
    C_Array: ["123", "456", "789"]
  },

  {
    A_ID: 'DEF',
    C_Array: ["444", "555", "666"]
  }
]
const newArray = data.map((outerNode) => {
  return outerNode.C_Array.map((innerNode) => {
    return {
      A_ID: outerNode.A_ID,
      C_ArrayValue: innerNode
    }
  })
});
console.log(newArray);
```